# Can't make works socket.io with my handshake

Tags: node.js, sockets, handshake

I don't understand where is my problem.
When I put this:

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(server).of("/");
```

I my handshake looks like running fine, but all my socket.io's event (like connection) never works.
And when I when i put this

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

I got this :

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'authorization'

If I remove my handshake, all the socket.io's will works, but i need it :/

Here my app.js

```
 const express = require('express')
    , app  = express()
    , http = require('http')
    , ejs = require('ejs')
    , server = http.createServer(app)
    , port = process.env.PORT || 1337
    , io = require('socket.io').listen(server).of("/")
    ;



module.exports = { app: app, server: server };
// Grab "cookie" and "connect" from express
var connect = require('express/node_modules/connect')
var cookie = require('express/node_modules/cookie')
var connectes =[];


app.configure(function(){
    this.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    this.use(express.cookieParser());
    this.use(express.json());
    this.use(express.urlencoded());
    this.sessionStore = new express.session.MemoryStore({ reapInterval: 60000 * 10 });
    this.use(express.session({
        "secret": "some private string",
        "store":  this.sessionStore                                            
    }));
});
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.get('/', [requireLogin], function(request, response) {
    var pseudo = request.session.pseudo;
    response.render('index.ejs.html',{connectes:connectes});
});

app.get('/login', function(request, response) {
    response.render('login.ejs.html');
});

app.post("/login", function(req, res){
    if (req.param("user") != "") {
        req.session.pseudo = req.param("user");
        //socket.set('pseudo',req.param("user"));
        connectes.push(req.param("user"));
        res.render('index.ejs.html',{connectes:connectes});
    }else{
        res.render('login.ejs.html');
    }
});


const parseCookie = require('connect').utils.parseCookie;
io.authorization(function (handshakeData, callback) {
    var cookies = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
    console.log(cookie);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("This never appear in log :/");
    socket.on('login',function(user,callback){
        var pseudoValide = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < connectes.length; i++) {
            if(connectes[i]==user.pseudo){
                pseudoValide = false;
                callback(true);
            }
        }
        if (pseudoValide) {
            socket.set('pseudo',user.pseudo);
            pseudo = user.pseudo;
            socket.broadcast.emit('newuser', pseudo);
            socket.broadcast.emit('nvluseronline', pseudo);
            connectes.push(pseudo);
            callback(false,pseudo);
        }
    });
    socket.on('message',function(message){
        messageUser = message.message;
        socket.get('pseudo',function(error, pseudo){
            io.sockets.emit('nouveauMessage',{pseudo:pseudo,message:messageUser});
        })
    });
    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        socket.get('pseudo',function(error, pseudo){
            connectes = unset(connectes, pseudo);
            io.sockets.emit('nvldisc', pseudo);
        })

    });
});

function unset(array, value){
    var output=[];
    var index = array.indexOf(value)
    {
        var j = 0;
        for(var i in array)
        {
            if (i!=index)
            {
                output[j]=array[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}

/** Middleware  */
function requireLogin (req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.pseudo) {
        console.log(req.session.pseudo);
        next();
    }else{
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
}


if (!module.parent) {
  server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Listening', this.address());
  })
}
```

Like you can see i'm a beginner lost !

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the [documentation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing) on authorization carefully. `authorization` method only exists for namespaces. When doing global authorization, you have to do:

```
io.configure(function (){
  io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
    callback(null, true); // error first callback style 
  });
});
```

It'll work fine if you have `.of("/")` as server endpoint, but it is a namespace. Without namespaces you would have to use above method.

Comment: Thank you guy, I understand where was my mistake and now all works perfectly ! :)